# vue 2.x ios safari crash on render

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, safari, vue.js

I can't really paste reproduction here, because it's happening in commercial project. I will try to describe it and maybe someone had same problem.

Vue 2.x, iOS 9.x, iPad and iPod

My page (one of layouts) crashes on Safari/Chrome on iOS, immediatly after page load. On ipad it gets refreshed and works. On iPod it crashes also on other pages and doesn't get refreshed.

Can't debug anyhow. I know there was a problem with ios 9 safari with too much javascript templating/too much js at all.

Do you know anything about that issue? Is it possible to debug it somehow? I thought I just accidentaly trigger some bug in safari, but different behavior in faster/slower devices says it's more like computing bug (iPhone 6s work like ipad)

Help, I cant rewrite everything to jQuery now :D

EDIT:

I initialized vue on DOMContentLoaded and it fixed iPad problem (so problem was maybe conflicts between html rendering by vue and browser), but slow 2014 iPod breaks anyway

Comment: This is how you can debug https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html
Also have you compiled everything corectly so It could work on most browsers and devices

Comment: I can debug because pages crash - and devtools close then.

What do you mean compiled? I have babel set to be correct on all devices, and it works on some of them with same system and safari versions

Comment: I had an issue with browser crashing too, and it was caused by using too much memory by accident in my JS code. Does it crash straight away or does it freeze a bit first? Try adding a `debugger` statement early on and step through the code to see what's going on.

Comment: `debugger` seems legit, normally I cant debug because it crashes immediatly after js is starting. I will try to debug if its a memory problem o a bug. (but I guess its a bug which causes memory problem)

Comment: Added debugger; statement and vue crashes on parseHTML function which gets whole $el as argument